# InkWell Splash Effect not showing over Image in Stack

Tags: flutter

I have a stacked widget. I want the splash effect of InkWell to display over the image in the stack but not over the add IconButton, instead I get this effect instead;

[image: Splash effect]

It goes under the IconButton but does not go over the image as intended.

Here is my code for the Stack;

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
    children: [
      Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 180.0),
        child: Material(
          color: const Color(0xFFFCECDE),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: onTap,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            splashColor: Colors.grey,
            child: Ink(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      urlImage,
                      height: 102.0,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4.0, 16.0, 4.0, 24.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                        Text(
                          price,
                          style: GoogleFonts.lexend(
                            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              color: Color(0xFFB71C1C),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 24.0,
          width: 24.0,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            color: Color(0xFF921616),
          ),
          child: const Center(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

What am I missing? I have tried placing Material and InkWell over the container but I still get the same effects.